# Adguard Home docker compose config and db missing

Tags: docker, docker-compose

im trying to run adguard with docker compose. I created a lot more containers with docker compose but this one is not creating any files into the mapped folder.

I tried to rebuild the docker command of the official instruction but any time i recreate the container i end up at the setup page and all settings are deleted.

Any ideas?

This is my compose file:

```
version: "3"
volumes:
    homematic_data:
        external: true 

networks:
  homematic:

services:
  samba:
    image: dperson/samba
    container_name: samba
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "137:137/udp"
      - "138:138/udp"
      - "139:139/tcp"
      - "445:445/tcp"
    healthcheck:
      disable: true
    environment:
      - TZ='Europe/Berlin'
      - WORKGROUP=workgroup
      - RECYCLE=false
      - USER1=pi;PASSWORD;1000
      - SHARE1=homematic_docker;/shares/homematic_docker;yes;no;yes;pi;pi
    volumes:
      - /home/pi:/shares/homematic_docker
    networks:
      - homematic
  promtail:
    image: grafana/promtail:latest
    container_name: promtail
    volumes:
      - /var/log:/var/log
      - ./promtail:/etc/promtail
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: -config.file=/etc/promtail/promtail-config.yml
    networks:
      - homematic
  node-exporter:
    image: quay.io/prometheus/node-exporter:latest
    container_name: node_exporter
    volumes:
      - /proc:/host/proc:ro
      - /sys:/host/sys:ro
      - /:/rootfs:ro
      - /:/host:ro,rslave
    command: 
      - '--path.rootfs=/host'
      - '--path.procfs=/host/proc' 
      - '--path.sysfs=/host/sys'
      - --collector.filesystem.ignored-mount-points
      - "^/(sys|proc|dev|host|etc|rootfs/var/lib/docker/containers|rootfs/var/lib/docker/overlay2|rootfs/run/docker/netns|rootfs/var/lib/docker/aufs)($$|/)"
    ports:
      - 9100:9100
    networks: 
      - homematic
    restart: always
###################### portainer
  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer-ce:latest
    container_name: portainer
    restart: unless-stopped
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./portainer:/data
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
  adguard:
    image: adguard/adguardhome
    container_name: adguard
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 53:53/tcp 
      - 53:53/udp
      - 67:67/udp 
      - 69:68/udp
      - 80:80/tcp 
      - 443:443/tcp 
      - 443:443/udp 
      - 3000:3000/tcp
      - 853:853/tcp
      - 784:784/udp 
      - 853:853/udp 
      - 8853:8853/udp
      - 5443:5443/tcp 
      - 5443:5443/udp
#    environment:
#      - TZ=Europe/Berlin
    volumes:
      - /home/pi/homematicDocker/adguard/work:/opt/adguardhome/work\
      - /home/pi/homematicDocker/adguard/conf:/opt/adguardhome/conf\
#    network_mode: host
  raspberrymatic:
    image: ghcr.io/jens-maus/raspberrymatic:3.67.10.20230117-27abde9
    container_name: homematic
    hostname: homematic-raspi
    privileged: true
    restart: unless-stopped
    stop_grace_period: 30s
    volumes:
      - homematic_data:/usr/local:rw
      - /lib/modules:/lib/modules:ro
      - /run/udev/control:/run/udev/control
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "2001:2001"
      - "2010:2010"
      - "9292:9292"
      - "8181:8181"
    networks:
      - homematic
```

Comment: Could you please provide more details about which service/directory/volume has problems?

Comment: Sure. The service "Adguard" has the issue. The mapped directories on my raspberry pi are "conf" and "work" withing the folder "/home/pi/HomematicDocker/adguard". If I delete the folder "adguard", "conf" and "work"  will be created on recreation of the container but they stay empty.

Comment: Can you see any files in those folders from within container? Also please run `docker container inspect` again adguard container.

Answer (score 1):

Within the folder "/opt/adguardhome/work" I see a folder data with a database inside. After i finished the setup also the folder conf inside the container has a yaml file.

Unfortunately i copied the backslashes of the docker command into the volume mapping, thats was the problem why i didnt get any data. Thank you Mike!